# Is there a way to decline a transaction based PayPal IPN data or user data?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have PayPal integrated on a website using "PayPal Payments Standard."

It works just fine but now I would like to add some more functionality to it. The main issue I have is that I would like to only accept payment from buyers whose shipping address is in a specific country.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm assuming that it is too late once I receive the IPN message to refuse the payment. Maybe there is a way to tell PayPal in the original request that shipping addresses have to be in a specific country?

Or do I have to go as far as implementing my own shopping cart and uploading the cart to PayPal? If I did this I could control shipping locations with PHP before every contacting PayPal. This would just be a lot of extra work that I don't want to get into right now though.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to deny payment based on shipping address country through a PayPal Payments Standard form.

Answer (score 0):

little search on google

[paypal forums](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/How-to-use-PayPal-Archive/How-do-you-restrict-which-countries-you-ship-to/td-p/12868)